# How to replace font tags with span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to replace all instances of a font
tag that has a color attribute like this:

```
<font color="red">Some text</font>
```

with this:

```
<span style="color: red;">Some text</span>
```

I did some hunting on StackOverflow and found this link, and modeled my code after it:
[Javascript JQuery replace tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478950/javascript-jquery-replace-tags)

I've created a little jQuery loop below that is supposed to do the following:

1. Go through the string(contents of a div)
2. Get the font color attribute
3. Replace the  tags with a
4. Set a CSS style attribute with the appropriate color.

Right now, it doesn't work.  I just get an error stating that 'replaceWith' is not a function.

```
$('font').each(function () {
    var color;
    this.$('font').replaceWith(function () {
        color = this.attr("color");
        return $('<span>').append($(this).contents());
    });
    this.$("span").attr("style", "color=" + color);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where did you learn about `this.$`

Comment: oh sorry, I use backbone.js and that's a construct from backbone.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need for each, replaceWith will do it internally.

```
$("font").replaceWith(  //find all font tags and call replace with to change the element
    function(){
        var tag = $(this);
        return $("<span/>")  //create new span
                   .html(tag.html())  //set html of the new span with what was in font tag
                   .css("color", tag.attr("color"));  //set the css color with the attribute
    }
);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qggadmmn/

Comment: This will fail if `<font>` elements are nested.

Comment: only 6 yers tool late @RokoC.Buljan and it was not nested here so it worked for the original poster.

Comment: It's never too late for a public page - to *hint with a comment* that the the provided code is not recursive ;) - just in case someone has i.e: `<font color="#f00">Hello <font color="#0ff">world</font></font>` which is pretty common on legacy websites that still use the deprecated `<font>` tag.

Comment: So quick hack would be `while($("font").length) $("font").replaceWith(...)` or `$($("font").get().reverse()).replaceWith(...)` or instead of tag.html() append the children. The original code did not have nested tags, hence the orginal answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('font').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var color = $this.attr('color');
    var text = $this.text();
    var span = $('<span style="' + color '">' + text + '</span>';
    $this.before(span);
    $this.remove();
});
```

Comment: As a code-only answer, this completely fails to point out that it will *destroy* any HTML that may be nested inside the `<font>` tag.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You are right but I assumed "Some text" is some text not html. If there is html nested there You are right.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a late answer, but I think it's still worth it posting.

If your `font` tags may have other attributes than just `color` (ie: `face`, `size`), this would cover them all:

**HTML (Example)**

```
<font color="red" size="3">Some text</font>
<br />
<font color="blue" face="Verdana">Some text</font>
```

**jQuery (Javascript):**

```
$(function () {
    var fontSizes = [ 
        'xx-small', // 1
        'x-small',  // 2
        'small',    // 3
        'medium',   // 4
        'large',    // 5
        'x-large',  // 6
        'xx-large'  // 7
    ];

    $('font').replaceWith(function () {
        var attrs = this.attributes;
        var span = $('<span />').append($(this).contents());

        for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
            var name = attrs[i].name;
            var value = attrs[i].value;

            if (name.indexOf('face') >= 0) {
                name = 'font-family';
            }

            if (name.indexOf('size') >= 0) {
                name = 'font-size';
                value = fontSizes[value - 1];
            }

            span.css(name, value);
        }

        return span;
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/Lyqa84ea/3/)